# How binary search tree insertion works using recursion?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

I'm having some trouble understanding the recursive part of binary search tree insertion.

```
bstnode* insert(bstnode* root,int data)
{
    if(root==NULL){
        bstnode* tmp= new bstnode();
        tmp->data=data;
        tmp->left=tmp->right=NULL;
        return tmp;
    }

    if(data<root->data)     
        root->left = insert(root->left, data); 
    else 
        root->right = insert(root->right, data); //can't understand the logic here
    return root; 
}

/* consider following BST with their addresses[]:
              15 [100]
             /  \
           10    20 [200]
                   \
                   tmp [300]  
*/
```

According to me `root->right = insert(root->right, data);` should store the address of the newly created node in `root->right` so this code shouldn't work for tree with height>2.

However, it is working perfectly for any number of nodes.
I must be missing some crucial details here.
suppose I want to insert 25 in BST i.e. insert(root,25);
as 25>15:- 
I'm breaking down the recursive part here:
`root->right = insert(root->right, 25);`
or `15->right = insert(15->right,25);` Here, recursively calling it again because 25>20 
`insert(root->right, 25)` => `root->right->right` = `insert(root->right->right, 25);`
or `insert(15->right, 25)` => `20->right` = `insert(20->right, 25);`

`insert(20->right,25)` is `NULL` so a new node `tmp` is created.
`insert(20->right,25);` returns `tmp`.
unwinding the recursion now.

```
//20->right = insert(20->right, 25);
```

so,

`20->right=` 300 (tmp address);

```
//insert(15->right, 25) => 20->right
//and 15->right = insert(15->right,25);
```

`15->right = 20->next;`
therefore `15->right` = [300] address.
or
`root->right` = [300] address.
what's wrong with my approach?
Again an overview of recursive calls:

```
15->right = insert(15->right,25);
15->right = [20->right = insert(20->right,25)]; //20->right is NULL so creating new node
15->right = [20->right=   300 address of tmp];
15->right = [20->right or 300]
15->right = [300] // but in reality 15->right = [200]
```

Comment: `root->right = root->right->right = tmp;` - where did that first `root->right =` come from? It seems to have appeared from nowhere...

Comment: it's from condition 25>15

Comment: Wrong... what does `insert(root->right, 25)` return?

Comment: it's a recursive function and after reaching the base case it returns new node which sets to root->right->right then it unwinds once more to root->right

Comment: Jerry you are forgetting when it unwinds the pointer returned to the previous function has changed the one from the root of the level above it

Comment: To show this right before you return root print the pointer value to the command line

Comment: whats wrong is this line in your thinking right here                                      15->right = 20->next;   it should be 15->right = 20;  remember your function returns root, not root->right

Comment: @Steve so you're saying that 20->right automatically becomes 20 when returning..if that's the case then it should be true for all return(ptr->next).i.e. it should return ptr instead of ptr->next but, it's not true.

Comment: Jerry,  yes, look at what the function returns it returns root, not root->right.  It always returns whatever was passed into the function as root. look at the code the last line is return root; not return (root->right);

Comment: @Steve I cross checked by writing code and found that return(root) and return(root->left) prints different outputs.

Comment: And if you do return(root->right) it will be different to. Let me see if I can think of a better way to illustrate it to you when I have some more time.

Comment: I updated my answer see if the bottom makes sense to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are forgetting that root->right is the root->right of the address you are passing into the function as root.  every call to insert passes in root->right or root->left depending on which way you traverse.

This statement is incorrect:

```
root->right = root->right->right = tmp;
```

once an iteration of the function is returned it is removed from the stack so in this case we have 3 calls  I will put your numbers in place of the pointer value.

```
insert(15->right,25)
insert(20->right,25)
```

the last one is null so it creates the node with 25 and returns it to the call insert(20->right,25) and sets 25 as 20->right so you have a tree that looks like this

```
/* consider following BST with their addresses[]:

              20 [200]
               \
                25 [300]  
*/
```

it then returns this tree to the call insert(15->right,25) and sets that trees right to the tree we just returned which so we get your final tree

```
/* consider following BST with their addresses[]:
          15 [100]
         /  \
       30    20 [200]
               \
                25 [300]  
*/
```

EDIT:  let me see if I can clarify.  Lets look at your tree again

```
/* consider following BST with their addresses[]:
          15 [100]
         /  \
       10    20 [200]
               \
               tmp [300]  
*/
```

we want to insert 25 so we call (again I will use the value at that node of the tree to represent the pointer we are passing)
    insert(15, 25)

this then calls insert on root->right which happens to be 20

```
insert(20, 25)
```

this calls insert again on 20 right node now which happens to be null

```
insert(null,25)
```

so lets now look at the returns

insert(null,25) returns a node with 25 in it and then is remove from the stack

```
 return 25;
```

insert(20,25) gets its return of a node with 25.  it sets its right child to 25 which looks like this

```
 20->right = 25;
 return 20;
```

now we are back to the original call of insert(15,25).  it got returned 20.  so it does

```
15->right = 20;
return 15;
```

Comment: "it then returns this "TREE" to the call insert(15->right,25)" no.. first 20->right stores the address of  insert(25->right,25) then root->right stores the address of 20->right. which is again 300.

Comment: Sorry it should have been it returns the pointer to the root of the sub-tree

Comment: oh yes..it's right.. return is from last statement return root; that's why it is returning root instead of root->right. how could I've not noticed it..pheww finally get it.

Comment: Yes there you go. I'm glad I could get it out there in a way you could see it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the confusion may be coming from two different sources for you.
First the tree commented into your code would not be possible. Second is that a new node is only created when the function is passed in a null pointer. Only values less than 15 can go to the left. It would be something like this instead (depending on add order):

```
   15
  /  \
     20
    /  \
       30
```

When you go to add 25 to this it will end up as follows:

```
   15
  /  \
     20
    /  \
        30
       /
      25
```

I will try and step through the code on this to explain. When adding 25 to the original tree on the first function call the first node is not NULL and 25 > 15 so the

```
else
{ 
    root->right = insert(root->right, data);
}
```

is called. This calls the same insert function recursively but is now using the 20 node as it's comparison. Again not null and 25 > 20 so call insert on right node as above. This again calls the recursive function but now on 30. 25<30 so it calls the function on the left node. At this point the function as been passed in a NULL pointer as there is nothing there and a new node is created and placed in this spot.

Comment: 30 was a typo mistake..I've corrected it."The functions all then return this newly created node all the way back to the original function call." how? can you elaborate this with example.

Comment: It does not return it all the way back to the original call. You have to work back down the stack of each iteration of the call to insert. It returns pointers to larger subtrees until it gets back to the original call

Comment: Sure. In hindsight my wording is a little unclear, and upon further inspection not true I will edit to remove. The return is actually just utilized to set the correct node to the right or left when it is created in the right spot.

Answer (score 0):

In a way you are correct. You can never have a sub-tree (not tree) of height >2.

In this code, you will never have a `root->right->right` because, as far as the code is concerned, when you call 
          `root->left = insert(root->left, data);`

the (local) root pointer is now pointing to the node you just inserted. the (local) root is pointing to `root->left.`

Therefore, you CAN have a tree of any height(However, the local root pointer is pointing to a sub-tree of height <2)

Answer (score 0):

Note that `insert()` always returns the `root` that was passed to it as an argument unless `root == NULL`. There's therefore no way for the new node you insert to "walk up the tree". What happens in the recursive call doesn't matter -- you always return the same `root` that you were passed in the non-`NULL` case.

Despite the way some people teach recursion, I think it helps (for my brain anyway) to *not* try to unroll the recursion, and instead consider whether the logic makes sense:

If you are passed a non-`NULL` node and `data < root->data`, would you get the correct result if you do `root->left = insert(root->left, data)` and assume the `insert()` magically "just works" (i.e., that it inserts `data` into the left tree and returns the root of that tree)?

If the logic checks out for both the left and right case, you then consider the base case: If you are passed a `NULL` node, will you return the correct one-element tree?

If the logic checks out for the base case too, then you know your code must be correct, since the recursive steps make sense and you know that you will land in a base case that also makes sense (since you will eventually reach a `NULL` node as you walk down the tree).

Comment: "What happens in the recursive call doesn't matter -- you always return the same root" no.. function doesn't work when i use insert(root->right, data); instead of root->right = insert(root->right, data);

Comment: @JerryGoyal: It works if you think of the job of `insert()` as being to insert `data` into the tree you give as the first argument and return a pointer to the new tree. (In this case the pointer will usually be the same as the old `root->right` in practice, but it will be different if `root->right` was `NULL` and a new element is inserted.)

Comment: i.e., `insert(tree, data)` inserts `data` into `tree` and returns a pointer to the resulting tree. To insert a new element into the right sub-tree of `root` and make the resulting tree the new right sub-tree, you therefore do `root->right = insert(root->right, data)`.

Comment: So the general approach is to assume that `insert(tree, data)` will do just that, and structure your recursive case around that assumption. Once the recursive case "makes sense", you turn to the base case (`root == NULL`) and make sure it works too. Since your recursive case and base case both make sense at that point, there is no point where the code can break, and therefore it must be correct. I'm sorry if this way of thinking isn't helpful to you, but it's the easiest way for me to convince myself that a recursive algorithm is correct.

Comment: If that's a bit vague, consider the following: If the base case is correct, then you know that the algorithm will work for a tree of height 1. For a tree of height 2, you know that the recursive case is correct, and therefore it must work too (since the recursive call lands you in the base case). For a tree of height 3, you know that trees of height 2 work. Since the recursive case is correct, this means that trees of height 3 will work too. You can go on like that forever, and therefore the algorithm must work for all trees, regardless of height.

Comment: your theoretical approach sounds good.. but here I'm more concerned about the practical implementation and grasping the true logic instead of some assumptions.

Comment: @JerryGoyal: That is the true logic behind recursion. Once you get to a thousand levels of recursion, you can't unroll the code all the way to the bottom in your head any more, so you will have to use reasoning similar to the above instead. Once you "get the hang" behind recursive thinking, you can also start to see how things will be executed though.

Comment: It's only an "assumption" while you're putting together the algorithm. Once you've put together the recursive case (assuming that the function is already correct while doing so) and the base case, you know that the algorithm itself will be correct (provided you don't have any bugs under the assumption), and so it ceases to be an assumption at that point.